# How to show a row for each column?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to order my products in 4 columns and expecting that they array in a way similar like this:

`1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8 
9 10 11 12`

but in the moment they show like this:

`1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.`

What could be the mistake?

```php
global $woocommerce_loop, $woocommerce;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'per_page'  => '12',
    'columns'   => '4',
    'future' =>'yes',
    'order' => 'asc'
), $atts));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'product_type' , 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'lottery')),
    'meta_key' => '_lottery_dates_to',
    'is_lottery_archive' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Is this "showing" on the front-end? It is not clear.

Comment: yes, this code renders a shorcode which then i place on the front-end

Comment: `display: flex` would solve your layouting issue. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CSS issue rather than a php issue. Try using a `grid`-example:

```css
.all-my-products {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
}
.products {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-my-products">
    <div class="products">Product 1 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 2 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 3 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 4 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 5 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 6 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 7 <button>BUY</button></div>
    <div class="products">Product 8 <button>BUY</button></div>
</div>
```